# How come Gradle doesn't see plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

```
$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

I wrote a Gradle plugin that has a task called `manageVersion`, and it's being used in a lot of our microservices. Here's the our `build.gradle` file structure common to all of our microservices.

```
import com.company.utilities.WidgetVersionPlugin

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url 's3://' + s3_bucket
      authentication {
          awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
      }
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.company.utilities:widget-version-plugin:3.3.+"
  }
}


plugins {
    id "com.company.microservice.root.java" version "2.0.19"
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: WidgetVersionPlugin
    ...
}
```

When I run a Gradle command, e.g., `./gradlew clean` for example, I do see the `com.company.utilties:widget-version-plugin:3.3.1` being downloaded in my Gradle cache as expected, if it's not already there. So far this has been working.

Now I implement the **same** `build.gradle` in a **new** project, and when I run `./gradlew clean`, I get

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'company-lambda-runner'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.company.utilities.WidgetVersionPlugin']
   > Could not create task ':manageVersion'.
      > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Substituting strings within the `buildscript` block is usually not a good idea.

Comment: It's worked for us so far, until now. But even w/o the string substitution it still fails the same way.

Comment: Try running with `--stacktrace` (or `-S`) to get the stack trace for the exception like the build output advises. You probably have a bug in the plugin where it gets an unexpected null value.